# Expectation of the Ito Integral and optional sampling

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Example:

$(W_{t},\mathcal{F}_{t})$ is standard Brownian.

$\cos^{2}W(t)=1+ \underbrace{-2\int_{0}^{t}\cos(W_{s})\sin(W_{s})dW_{s}}_{=:M_{t}} +\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}[2-4\cos^{2}(W_{s})]ds $ by Ito's formula.

$\Rightarrow E[\cos^{2}W(t)]$ contains term $E[M_{t}]\overset{\text{optional sampling}}=E[M_{0}] \overset{?}=1$

First, I do not see how this term is $1$ and not $0$ given we are now evaluating the upper bound of the integral at $0$.

Second, given that it is then the case that optional sampling can be applied, would this then imply that **any** expectation of this form (expectation of ito integrals which are also martingales) is going to be $0$ given that the upper bound will always be evaluated at $0$?